# Configuration Checklist does not stay green

Tags: configuration

WP 4.9.9 and CiviCRM 5.2.1
When going through the Configuration Checklist and completing items and after logging out and back in to CiviCRM the checklist items returns to red.  How can we keep them green?
THANKS.

Comment: Pretty sure that is normal behaviour - it does not stay green :-(

Comment: Doesn't sound right. The Checklist, once done, should stay green imo.

Comment: I've worked with about 10 different CiviCRM systems over the years.  I've seen both situations... stays green and revert back to red...   oh well... not a big deal but very confusing and not very reassuring for new users to CiviCRM!!!